# neovim: command not behaving as expected for text objects such as parentheses

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a caret on line 8:

[image]

I do `c+i+(` and this is what I get:

[image]

But I would expect it to go into test2() parenthesis as this is where the caret was when i did the combo. It doesn't. It goes all the way up to the callback().

Why is that happening and how to workaround it?

Code:

```
/* eslint-disable */

function callback(fn: Function) {
    return fn();
}

const whatever = callback(function test1() {
    function test2() {}

    return test2;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nominal behavior:**

If the cursor is between an opening parenthesis and a closing parenthesis (inclusive), then the expected behavior of `<operator>i(` is to "operate" on the text located between those two parentheses.

Same logic for `a(`.

**Fallback behavior:**

If there are no parentheses *around* the cursor, then the expected behavior is to "operate" on the content of the closest pair of parentheses *forward*.

Same logic for `a(`.

In short, you appear to want the *fallback* behavior despite being in a situation that favors the *nominal* behavior:

```
                         +-- opening parenthesis before the cursor
                         |
const whatever = callback(function test1() {
    function test2() {}

    return test2;
});
 |
 +-- closing parenthesis after the cursor
```

In that context, what is happening when you do `ci(` is a) totally normal and expected, and b) not what you want. Therefore, you will have to use a different command, more in line with what you actually want to happen.

All the following commands do what you want:

```
f(a
f)i
t)a
f(ci(
f)ci(
```

…and there are certainly other ways. `f(a` is the more intuitive, IMO.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. `f` is great! I wonder if remapping `ci(` to `f(ci(` is a good idea? But I guess I shouldn't fight with the defaults! Thanks again

Comment: @feerlay you might like to have a look at this plugin: https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim